# How to display string[] value in Toast Message Box?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Environment.I have to display Toast message box using the String[] value.But the Toast message Syntax cannot accept the String[] value.How can i display message the String[] value by Using Toast.The Toast can accept the CharSequence only.how can i change the String[] value into CharSequence?

Here i am using this code to display String[] Value:

```
 public static String[] sysid1;
 sysid1= PerformCommand(inCmd,"","",m_SystemID, m_Username,m_Password,m_Data);
 Toast toast=Toast.makeText(EpicClub.this,sysid1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show()
```

Comment: Replace sysis1 to sysid1.toString() in Toast toast=Toast.makeText(EpicClub.this,sysid1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

Comment: Toast toast=Toast.makeText(EpicClub.this,sysid1[0].toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16009621/1168654

Comment: You can convert `String[]` to `String` via `StringBuffer` for example ad then assign `buffer.toString()` to `Toast`.

Comment: @Sajmon he can use the array index to display the toast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the String array to string using :

```
String sysid1String = Arrays.toString(sysid1)
```

and then pass `sysid1String` it as argument to `Toast.makeText`

like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sysid1String ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your Response @codeMan.I try your code,but it is not working.While Debugging my code.It cannot step over into the Toast Syntax.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try using this line of code : Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),sysid1String ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

You can output a String using a Toast.
What you're trying to do is output an Array of Strings.

Depending on what you want to output either concatenate the Strings, or select the String at your required index and select that for output.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use like:

```
String[] sysid1 = {"a","b"};  

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+Arrays.toString(sysid1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have array of strings as below. You can use the array index to display the toast.

```
 public static String[] sysid1={"hello","hi"};
 Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,sysid1[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 toast.show();
```

Instead of string array you can use a arraylist

```
   ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
   al.add("hello");
   al.add("hi");
   Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,al.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);// use the index to get the string
   toast.show();
```